# Вызов дочерней функции из родительского компонента

Tags: vue.js, vue3

В дочернем компоненте делаю запрос к БД и формирую таблицу. При нажатии на строку таблицы отправляю ивент к родителю, чтобы открыть медальное окно. Подскажите, как мне удалить строку из таблицы при нажатии на кнопку внутри модального окна, которе находится в родителе.

сейчас я передаю через event задаю ссылку на функцию, но хочется найти более элегантное решение

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В данном случае у вас нарушается принцип ответственности - родительский компонент выводит кнопку удаления из таблицы, о которой он ничего не знает, т.к. она находится в дочернем компоненте. Необходимо получать данные в родительском компоненте и передавать их массивом дочернему компоненту в виде параметра, чтобы он формировал таблицу. А по нажатию на кнопку в модальном окне, удалять строку из массива, дочерний компонент перерисует таблицу автоматически.